# Why does the computation time significantly change when I call both functions or switch functions?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, gpu

I have some trouble understanding why the computation time spikes significantly in my program.

I am trying to obtain some indices and I want to time which one is faster. The following code is part of a class:

```
def _obtain_indices(self):
"""
Set the indices of the object for all
indices that exceed a threshold. 
Parameters
----------
tensor: array like
    Tensor of which to select elements

Returns
-------
None      
"""
start = datetime.now()
abs_tens = torch.abs(self.residual_grad)
end = datetime.now()
t_abs = (end - start)/timedelta(milliseconds=1)

# Func gauss
start = datetime.now()
self.indices = self.compress(abs_tens, self.K)
end = datetime.now()
t_gauss = end - start
t_gauss = t_gauss/timedelta(milliseconds=1)

# Func top_k
start = datetime.now()
self.indices = torch.topk(abs_tens, int(self.K))[1]
end = datetime.now()
t_topk = end - start
t_topk = t_topk/timedelta(milliseconds=1)

wandb.log({'t_abs' : t_abs, 't_gauss': t_gauss, 'top-k': t_topk})
```

Now there's some trouble here. `wandb.log()` logs the values.

I have some example output graphs:
[image]

This is with the original code above. When I switch the functions (`TopK` first, `Gauss`second) I get the following graph:

[image]

When I remove the `TopK` code:
[image]

When I remove the `Gauss` code:
[image]

What is happening? I was thinking maybe something with heap allocation, but I'm not sure and feel unqualified to make statements about it. Can somebody point me in the right direction?